# Confused with mysql query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a database that stores products from kmart and walmart. Some kmart and walmart products are the same and this is stored in a matchedProducts table with recording a match with their real stockcodes (each vendor's stockcodes are unique).

However in the main table which is currentProducts, that table has all the products in it, and every time a search is performed, a search over matchedProducts is also performed to see if the query can deliver products with their matches and everything is working fine, except if you see the code below:

```
SELECT cp.brand, cp.name, cp.quantity, cp.unitPrice, cp.price, cp.stockcode as fakeStockcode,
cp.vendor, pk.stockcode as realStockcode,
(CASE 
WHEN (vendor = 1) 
THEN 
(SELECT walmart FROM matchedProducts mp WHERE realStockcode = mp.kmart)
ELSE 
(SELECT kmart FROM matchedProducts mp WHERE realStockcode = mp.walmart)
END) as realMatchingStockcode,
(SELECT productKey FROM productKeys WHERE productKeys.stockcode = realMatchingStockcode) as fakeMatchingStockcode,
(SELECT brand FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingBrand,
(SELECT name FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingName,
(SELECT price FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingPrice,
(SELECT unitPrice FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingUnitPrice
FROM currentProducts cp
LEFT JOIN productKeys pk ON cp.stockcode = pk.productKey
WHERE name LIKE "%coffee%" LIMIT 300
```

That code above is extremely laggy and it's due to this part below:

```
(SELECT brand FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingBrand,
    (SELECT name FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingName,
    (SELECT price FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingPrice,
    (SELECT unitPrice FROM currentProducts WHERE currentProducts.stockcode = fakeMatchingStockcode) as matchingUnitPrice
```

Those four lines of code make the query lag a lot more than without it, but are necessary for getting the details of the matching product from the opposing vendor. Is there anyway to re write this query or restructure the query to make it more efficient and faster?

I'm not very good at SQL, so I'm sure I have written it very well at all, any help would be much appreciated!

edit: sample data

Current Products table:

```
  Brand | Name | quantity | unitPrice | price | stockcode | vendor
    'calidad canon', 'Calidad Canon Printer Ink Pgi-650bk Black', 'each', '$0.00 / 0', '15', 'AAFF', '1'
'Cetaphil', 'Moisturising Bath & Wash', '230mL', '$3.70 per 100mL', '8.5', 'AAVb', '0'
'moki', 'Moki Noise Isolation Earbuds Black Or White', 'each', '$0.00 / 0', '10', 'AAWH', '1'
'lamb leg', 'Lamb Leg Steak Heart Smart', 'min. 300g', '$21.00 / 1KG', '6.3', 'AAiN', '1'
'heinz simply food', 'Heinz Simply Food 6 Months Banana Custard', '120g', '$1.25 / 100G', '1.5', 'AAle', '1'
'aroma essentials', 'Aroma Essentials Candle Lemongrass & Ginger', '300g', '$5.00 / 100G', '15', 'AAuL', '1'
'maybelline great lash big', 'Maybelline Great Lash Big Mascara Blackest Black', '10ml', '$9.05 / 10ML', '9.05', 'AAuX', '1'
```

Matched Products table:

```
matchId | walmartProductId | kmartProductId
'1', '9240819P', '380151'
'2', '9224109P', '724631'
'3', '9224153P', '724633'
'4', '7422859P', '322001'
'5', '9088598P', '568518'
'6', '6803008P', '16578'
```

Product keys table (table that records real stockcode vs generated stock code):

```
stockcode | productKey
'7230', 'AAFF'
'2459250P', 'AAVb'
'364440', 'AAWH'
'209458', 'AAiN'
'362691', 'AAle'
'565835', 'AAuL'
```

Comment: Some sample data would be nice here.  Even if you get an answer, your question would still be incomplete IMO as it is not clear what problem your query is solving.

Comment: Hey, updated with sample data :)

Comment: You could replace the 4 subqueries by one `left join`, but the actual issue is probably that you do not have an index on `currentProducts.stockcode` (which you would need for the `left join` too), so you should check (and add) that, it might also be a candidate for the primary key. If that does not help, add the explain output to your question (run `explain select cp.brand, ...`).